# How to make lines from your scatter plot points to the horizontal axis

Tags: excel, matlab, plot, scatter-plot

in excel, in order to have drop line in a line chart you just click the  line output, and then drop line, but if your plot is scatter plot then you will click error bars, set to minus, no cap, and 100 percent and you will have almost the same output. but i don't know if Matlab can do that, please help
this is my x, y data:

```
x=28,35,44,57,68,70,85
y= 5,6,14,10,17,7,8,5
```

i don't know if matlab can do dropping line if your data is scatter data, please help me thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`stem` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem.html?refresh=true) instead of `plot`. Much easier than in Excel, no hacks required.

```
x = [28, 35, 44, 57, 68, 70, 85];
y = [5,  6,  14, 17, 7,  8,  5 ];

stem(x,y)
```

Comment: can i modify the plot? the size, color etc? and also how to put labels on each data points?  thanks, by the way it works :)

Comment: check the link @Dan provided everything is there.

Comment: The same way you would using `plot`... e.g. `stem(x,y,'r','LineWidth',8)`

Comment: As for data labels, I've never tried that and it might be built in too but otherwise here is a file exchange entry: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46891-labelpoints